# C# ошибка CS1069

Tags: c#, графика

Кто-нибудь знает, что это за ошибка и как её исправить? Когда вместо System.Drawing пишу System.Drawing.Common, выдаёт ошибку о несуществовании такого пространства имён.
На сатйе Microsoft ничего не написано об этой ошибке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: NuGet пакет **System.Drawing.Common** установите.